# why are some keyframes being skipped by the RigController?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

public void Equip(RaycastWeapon newWeapon)
{
if (weapon)
{

```
        Destroy(weapon.gameObject);

    }

    weapon = newWeapon;
    weapon.raycastDestination = crosshairTarget;
    weapon.transform.parent = weaponParent;
    weapon.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    weapon.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
    rigController.Play("equip_" + weapon.weaponName);

    shootBtn.SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question posted. what you want to achieve and what is the issue.Thanks

Comment: I am working on a gameobject that is constraint to two sourceobjects in the Multi-Parent Constraint... I am trying to switch the priorities of the source objects through code and it is turning into a nightmare